# Restricting new tabs from javascript, multiple tabs/windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, c, tabs

I have a requirement where upon some event I need to open new tab/window(Event like opening new tab at 11 am, not the user initiated events like mouse click) I open a new tab/window from javascript.

The issue is, if there are 3 tabs opened up of my page then they open 3 new tabs. I just want to restrict the number of new tabs to one.

For eg. If there are 3 tabs then open only 1 new tab.

Is this possible through javascript?
If server side code required, how can it help in solving this problem?

Comment: are you using any bootstrap ?

Comment: no, i am not using any bootstrap

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs ..is this the way you are looking for ?